# Can copy HTML formatted text from clipboard in silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, clipboard

I need to access clipboard in silverlight.

in winform apllication:

```
textBox1.Text = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Html);
```

but, in silverlight I can only get text

```
textBlock1.Text = Clipboard.GetText();
```

How can I get the html format of the clipboard ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently [this is not supported](http://weblogs.asp.net/lduveau/archive/2009/11/21/silverlight-4-clipboard-access.aspx).